# Add an image to one side of cube

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to attach a few images to a few sides of a cube, and then leave the other sides blank. I'm having a very difficult time getting this to work. I can load the file and display it fine if I set all the sides to be one material, but if I try to set just one side to show the image, it just is blank.

```js
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();                             
var texture0 = textureLoader.load( 'images/0.png' );                       
var texture1 = textureLoader.load( 'images/1.png' );                       
var texture2 = textureLoader.load( 'images/2.png' );                       
var texture3 = textureLoader.load( 'images/3.png' );                       
var texture4 = textureLoader.load( 'images/4.png' );                       
var texture5 = textureLoader.load( 'images/5.png' );

var cubeMaterials = [                                                      
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture0 } ),                      
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture1 } ),                      
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture2 } ),                      
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture3 } ),                      
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture4 } ),                      
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture5 } )                       
];

var cubegeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(3,2,3);                          
let  cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubegeometry, cubeMaterials);                   
group.add( cube );
```

Comment: Do you want to apply different image to each side of the cube?

Comment: What version of THREE.js are you using? `THREE.CubeGeometry` has been deprecated in favor of `THREE.BoxGeometry` and `THREE.BoxBufferGeometry`.

Answer (score 7):

```
THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('your-img-url');
texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();

var cubeMaterial = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture //left
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 'orange' //right
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 'green' // top
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 'blue' // bottom
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 'pink' // front
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 'yellow' //back
    })
];
```