# A-frame - Is there a way to make an image show up on only one side of a shape?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I'm very new to A-frame and doing a project for my class that requires me to take a 2D image and use it in a 3D scene in whatever way I can come up with. For my project, I want the image to be displayed on multiple boxes, but only on the side that the camera sees first. Anytime I link an image to a shape, it will cover the whole shape as a texture. Is there a way to specify where it can show up on the shape?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [component](https://github.com/elbobo/aframe-multisrc-component) which allows you to use different materials for each side of a cube.

---

If You're interested in doing it by yourself then you could write a component which would

- load the texture
- create an array of six materials (one for each side) by only one textured
- use the array as the material of the cube

[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45522763/2425787):

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    schema: {
      img: {type: "selector"}
    },
    init: function() {
      // wait until the entity is loaded
      this.el.addEventListener("loaded", evt => {
        // grab the mesh
        const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
        // load the texture
        this.el.sceneEl.systems.material.loadTexture(this.data.img, {
            src: this.data.img
          },
          // when loaded, create 6 materials for each side
          function textureLoaded(texture) {
            var cubeMaterial = [
              //left
              new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture}),
              //right
              new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'orange'}),
              // top
              new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'green'}),
              // bottom
              new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'blue'}),
              // front
              new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({olor: 'pink'}),
              //back
              new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'yellow'})
            ];
            // apply the new material + clean up the old one
            var oldMaterial = mesh.material;
            mesh.material = cubeMaterial;
            oldMaterial.dispose()
          });
      });
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="lobster" src="https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpeg" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </a-assets>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="45 -45 0" foo="img: #lobster"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

if you try to find out on which side of the cube is your camera, then you can change the array, or add / remove the `map` attribute.